# How to use async await in ajax call using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, ajax, jquery-events

I used the async-await code in the script file. that script file called using ajax call. when I call ajax URL. it's not waited. it's going next line. this is my problem

**MY Scenario**

**a.html**

```
<script>

function call(){
  r =$.ajax({
      url: "/a/b",
      type: 'POST'
    })
}

$(document).ready(function(){
call()
console.log('hi')
})
</script>
```

**Ajax call code**

```
async function loadcontact(){  

  for(let i=0;i < 3; i++){  
let b = await i;  
console.log(b)  
}
}
```

**Excepted Output**

> 0
> 1
> 2
> hi

**I got output**

> 0
> hi
> 1
> 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How and when to use ‘async’ and ‘await’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

Comment: Your function `call` can be made to `async`, and you need to call it with `await`.  Then, the `document.ready` also needs to be made `async`

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/vfohugay/

Comment: @StefanN OP is asking about JavaScript, not C#; although the usage is basically identical, let's not confuse them with `public` and the like

Comment: @ChrisG  sees the example code. that also I tried but it's not working for me.

Comment: I tried many mays using the promise and jquery ajax also. but it's not working. how to achieve this solution.

Comment: 1. remove all unrelated code from your question, right now it's a mess 2. explain exactly how "it's not working" (which is a useless problem description), best by posting a [mre]

Comment: @ChrisG Ok I updated my comments and question.

Comment: I'm not seeing any update.

Comment: @ Chris G can you please check it. this my problem

Comment: @ChrisG can you please check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218017/discussion-between-hari-prasanth-and-chris-g).